# Can't run a simple Scala programme

Tags: scala

I‘m learning Scala by the book Programming in Scala. When I try to run the code given in the book, it gives me the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot figure out how to run target: File2
    at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27)
    at scala.tools.nsc.GenericRunnerCommand.scala$tools$nsc$GenericRunnerCommand$$guessHowToRun(GenericRunnerCommand.scala:38)
    at scala.tools.nsc.GenericRunnerCommand$$anonfun$2.apply(GenericRunnerCommand.scala:48)
    at scala.tools.nsc.GenericRunnerCommand$$anonfun$2.apply(GenericRunnerCommand.scala:48)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:108)
    at scala.tools.nsc.GenericRunnerCommand.<init>(GenericRunnerCommand.scala:48)
    at scala.tools.nsc.GenericRunnerCommand.<init>(GenericRunnerCommand.scala:17)
    at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner.process(MainGenericRunner.scala:33)
    at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner$.main(MainGenericRunner.scala:89)
    at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner.main(MainGenericRunner.scala)
```

How do I solve this?

Here's my code:

```
object Files2 {
  def filesHere = (new java.io.File(".")).listFiles
  def filesMatching(query: String, matcher: (String, String) => Boolean) = {
    for (file <- filesHere; if matcher(file.getName, query))
      yield file
  }

  def filesEnding(query: String) = filesMatching(query, _.endsWith(_))
  def filesContaining(query: String) = filesMatching(query, _.contains(_))
  def filesRegex(query: String) = filesMatching(query, _.matches(_))

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    println("filesEnding(\"scala\").toList [" + filesEnding("scala").toList + "]")
    println("filesContaining(\"Files1\").toList [" + filesContaining("Files1").toList + "]")
    println("filesRegex(\".*Re.ex.*\").toList [" + filesRegex(".*Re.ex.*").toList + "]")  
  }
}
```

Comment: How are you trying to run it?

Comment: Is it called `File2` (as mentioned in the error message) or `Files2` (as in your source file)?

Comment: Ahhhh,I found it.I mistook the object name....@Jesper

Comment: THX,I made a simple mistake....@Nicolas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just pasted your code into a file called `test.scala` and then ran it with `scala test.scala` and it worked fine.

```
dhg ~$ scala test.scala
filesEnding("scala").toList [List(./test.scala)]
filesContaining("Files1").toList [List()]
filesRegex(".*Re.ex.*").toList [List()]
```

Comment: THX,I just made a simple mistake

Comment: @NobToJuneau , dont forget to mark this as accepted answer (the check mark) if this answer met your requirement.

Answer (score 3):

The given file is not a script, it's a plain scala program, you need to compile it and then to run it. the error is due to the lack of compilation:

```
scalac Files2.scala
scala Files2
```

Comment: no,When I try scalac Files2.scala,there are no errors.When I try scala Files2,errors come.

Comment: Then it must be a typo, as pointed out by Jesper in the question comments.

Comment: @dhg As I haven't seen the typo, and due to the error message, I thought he try to execute `scala Files2` and if you don't want to add a `.scala`prefix, you need to compile first.